# Missing commits in repo on CircleCI container

Tags: android, git, github, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm using CircleCI to build an Android Github private project. Builds work fine but the commit history of `origin/master` on the container is different from what I get on my local machine.

I did a diff b/w output of `git rev-list origin/master` on my local machine and container and found quite a few differences - i.e. there are commits missing in the repo on the container.

I tried cloning the project from Github to my local machine and it showed me the same git commit history (correct commit count), is CircleCI doing something different?

Comment: The output of `git rev-list origin/master` does not matter. If the revision built by CircleCI is the right one, it's just okay. CircleCI could have a shallow-clone or a branch-specific fetch that does not touch its `origin/master`.

Comment: It matters for me because I'm using the output of `git rev-list --first-parent --count origin/master` as my app's versionCode actually! Also I'm sure that CircleCI is building on the master branch.

Comment: More info: I tried `git log --reverse` on the container, and that is not the initial commit.

Comment: What you need is `git rev-list --first-parent --count HEAD` in the container. Not `origin/master`. `HEAD` is the revision that has been built.

Comment: So I ran both `git rev-list --first-parent --count HEAD` and `git rev-list --first-parent --count origin/master` on the container and got the same output.

Comment: Then it's alright. `origin/master` records the status of `master` in the remote repository during last sync. It's not always the current head of `master` in the remote repository. It's quite normal that `origin/master` in your local maschine is different from the one in the container because they could sync with the remote repository at different moments.

Comment: But how can syncing at different moments lead to different commit histories? That too with missing commits?

Comment: 1. Your local machine syncs. The remote repository is updated by someone. The container syncs. It results in that the local machine has fewer commits than the container. 2. Your local machine makes a full clone but the container makes a shallow-clone, with `--depth=1` for example. Then the local machine has much more commits than the container. These are the possible cases that come to my mind.

Comment: TIL about shallow cloning and it is a shallow-clone issue! Found the circle.yml equivalent for doing a full clone here https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto/issues/103. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CircleCI 1.0 does a shallow clone, which is causing what you see.

Before cloning a repo, CircleCI checks to see if a "source cache" is available. If so, it uses it to recreate `.git/`. Then, on CircleCI 1.0, a shallow clone is done. On CircleCI 2.0 (in beta), a standard clone is done. Then, work is done to get to the correct commit/tag.

If you want to convert the repository on CircleCI 1.0 to an unshallow one, the following command does the trick:

```
"[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
```

On 1.0, the source cache is saved after the `dependencies` phase so I'd suggest not doing this after that phase so that the cache can be kept efficiently. For 2.0, it's saved when the [`save_cache`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#save_cache) step is run.

-Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the extra information!

Answer (score 1):

As @ElpieKay mentioned in the comments, this has to do with CircleCI shallow cloning the repo. Refer to https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto/issues/103 for circle.yml config for full cloning. For example, I did:

```
checkout:
    post:
        - "[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
```